# Why is this python request returning the same value each time?

Tags: python, python-requests, mediawiki-api

I'm using they python requests library for the first time, and I am confused. When I run the function below in a for loop, with different base URLs, it appears to receive a response, but the content that is returned is the same for both URLs.

If I look at the API URL in my browser, then I see that it's the content for the first URL that's being returned both times. What am I missing?

```
base_urls = ['http://kaweki.wikia.com/','http://solarmovie.wikia.com/']


def getEdits(wikiObj, limit=500):     
    payload = {'limit': limit}                             
    r = requests.get('{}api/v1/Activity/LatestActivity'.format(wikiObj),
                     params=payload)
    edits = r.json()
    return edits['items']

for url in base_urls:
    print getEdits(url)
```

Comment: I looked it over and can't see anything that's obviously problematic. Assuming both of the destination urls behave the same and have different content, then I can't explain why the results would appear the same.

Comment: Could it be a bug on their side? Maybe it's caching where it shouldn't?

Comment: I doubt it's caching that's the problem exactly, but I agree that it's totally possible the API is broken. It may also simply be hard to use, returning irrelevant results because of a non-obvious usage detail.

Comment: It's not only Python, it's the same when you place the request using `curl`. Funny enough, when you run the requests in your browser (chrome) you **will* get different results. I tried adding the header `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'` to the request but it didn't solve it. In order to further debug we need to see the server-side apache logs to see why it treats it as similar requests when it's done through code/curl and why it treats it as different requests when they're placed through a browser.

Comment: @Jeremy problem solved - see more details in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

There **is** a bug on the server side which ignores cache-control headers and such for a period of time.

Introducing sleep of 5 secs (maybe even shorter periods) works around the bug. I've marked the lines that were added below:

---

```
import requests
import json
from time import sleep #ADDED

base_urls = ['http://kaweki.wikia.com/', 'http://solarmovie.wikia.com/']


def getEdits(wikiObj, limit=500):       
    payload = {'limit': limit}   
    url = '{}api/v1/Activity/LatestActivity'.format(wikiObj)
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload) 
    edits = json.loads(r.content)
    return edits['items']

for url in base_urls:    
    print getEdits(url)  
    sleep(5) # ADDED
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
[{u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 14, u'user': 26127114, u'timestamp': 1424389645}, {u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 13, u'user': 26127114, u'timestamp': 1424389322}, {u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 12, u'user': 26127114, u'timestamp': 1424389172}, {u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 5, u'user': 26127114, u'timestamp': 1424388924}]
[{u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 14, u'user': 26127165, u'timestamp': 1424389107}, {u'article': 1461, u'revisionId': 7, u'user': 26127165, u'timestamp': 1424388706}]
```

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. But I think the `Host:` header might be a red herring. After all, `requests` already should add that by itself. And it does in fact seem to work with just the 5s delay.

Comment: @LukasGraf yes, you are right indeed! I'll update the answer - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The API endpoints are "broken". Refreshing the two endpoints in a browser repeatedly has them switching back and forth between two responses. You can replicate it by making refreshing one request half a dozen times, and then refreshing the other request half a dozen times and switching back and forth every half a dozen requests.

Request A:

```
http://solarmovie.wikia.com/api/v1/Activity/LatestActivity
```

Request B:

```
http://kaweki.wikia.com/api/v1/Activity/LatestActivity
```

Response 1:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127114,
            revisionId: 14,
            timestamp: 1424389645
        },
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127114,
            revisionId: 13,
            timestamp: 1424389322
        },
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127114,
            revisionId: 12,
            timestamp: 1424389172
        },
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127114,
            revisionId: 5,
            timestamp: 1424388924
        }
    ],
    basepath: "http://kaweki.wikia.com"
}
```

Response 2:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127165,
            revisionId: 14,
            timestamp: 1424389107
        },
        {
            article: 1461,
            user: 26127165,
            revisionId: 7,
            timestamp: 1424388706
        }
    ],
    basepath: "http://solarmovie.wikia.com"
}
```

Comment: While it's true it's not really helpful/useful! Further, can you reproduce the browser behavior with curl/python?

Comment: I've sent an email to their API team to let them know that it looks like there's a bug. Thanks so much!

Comment: @alfasin the question has the Python that originally showed the results. How is answer the question not useful?

Comment: I experienced the same behavior during testing this. So I think the correct answer here is in fact "this API is broken".

Comment: BTW: All the subdomains on `wikia.com` are just aliases (`CNAME` records) for `wikia.com`. So the distinction between different wikis has to happen via some sort of named virtual hosting based on the `Host:` header, which the API or some caching proxy in between seems to mess up.

Comment: I believe that @LukasGraf is correct. Something weird though: if I hardcode the Host header (i.e. `'Host': 'kaweki.wikia.com'`) - I'll get a different answer per request, but when I extract the host from `wikiObj` the bug is back. There's something messy here which I believe is both a combination of python dynamic binding with conjunction to the subdomain configuration on the server-side.

Comment: @abraham The OP showed a problem and you said - "hey there's a problem" and then you go into more details that shows how to repro the problem on a broaswer - but you didn't pinpoint the issue and introduced a way to fix/work-around it. That's why I wrote it's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and ran the script and got apparently identical output. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the script, though! I think the output is simply identical, for some reason. Try to change `return edits['items']` to just `return edits` and you'll see that the output is different in that case. If there really is a bug in the code, that should help you isolate it; if not, then maybe you can figure out why the real output is like that.